# 串 vs 丳: which one is used more often for "skewer"?

Tags: characters

I've seen that both 串 and 丳 are supposed to mean "skewer". Which one is more regularly used?

Are there other common use cases for 丳?

Comment: 串 is very common. 丳 is very obscure.

Comment: This is my very first time seeing this character 丳... I don't even know how to type it, either by Pinyin or by strokes, so I had to copy from your text...

Comment: Have never seen 丳 in my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the image results on Google [[串](https://www.google.hu/search?q=%E4%B8%B2&num=100&client=ubuntu&hs=9gx&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIzv-xovfkxwIVQsAUCh3GmwNk&biw=1366&bih=673), [丳]](https://www.google.hu/search?q=%E4%B8%B3&num=100&client=ubuntu&hs=v1c&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMI_-nOpPfkxwIVibMUCh3K7w3h&biw=1366&bih=673),  and Baidu [[串](http://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ipn=r&ct=201326592&cl=2&lm=-1&st=-1&fm=result&fr=&sf=1&fmq=1441629349903_R&pv=&ic=0&nc=1&z=&se=1&showtab=0&fb=0&width=&height=&face=0&istype=2&ie=utf-8&word=%E4%B8%B2), [丳]](http://image.baidu.com/search/index?tn=baiduimage&ps=1&ct=201326592&lm=-1&cl=2&nc=1&ie=utf-8&word=%E4%B8%B3), 串 is more commonly used as skewer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if any other common use cases for 丳?

Comment: I don't think this character has any other commonly used meaning. Baidu Baike does not mention any other than  'a metalic stick used to roast meat', i.e. skewer. http://baike.baidu.com/view/354667.htm

Answer (score 2):

As a native Chinese I can tell you that we barely use `丳`.

Answer (score 1):

skewer  英 [ˈskju:ə(r)]
    美 [ˈskjuɚ]
n.  串肉杆; 烤肉叉子; 叉状物; 针状物;

丳
读音: [chǎn]
部首: 丨 五笔: KKJK
释义: 烤肉用的铁扦。

串
读音: [chuàn]
部首: 丨 五笔: KKHK
释义: [chuàn]1.多个同类东西连贯在一起

This is the first time to see "丳". It's clear that "丳" is more exact to the meaning of "skewer".

Comment: So 丳 is when the skewer is an iron one! No wonder no one knows about it... They only sell wooden sticks on the streets, and the meat is normally light enough, so there's no need to use a couple of sticks. Now, if they start to sell an entire chicken or lamb on the stick maybe things will change.

Answer (score 0):

串 is the one Chinese speak and use everyday. And the other character is not used at all. Even as a Chinese ,I can't recognize the character in the first time. And this is the first time I see the character.therefore, 串(chuan) is the right answer.  And I don't know how you get to know 丳, but in our daily life, we can't see this word.